# Create VSCode Task to launch multiple debugger configurations

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I have multiple `dotnet core` API projects in my solution (.sln). In my `launch.json` file, I have a debugger configuration for each API. Right now, I manually launch the debugger for each of the APIs I want to run in debug mode.

Is it possible to create a VSCode task that will launch multiple debuggers for each of the APIs I want to debug? I have several tasks to build the projects but can't figure out how to create a debug task.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know you can create a

> compound launch configuration

in VSCode. https://vscode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/editor/debugging/#launchjson-attributes

Comment: The link you provided is broken.